# Combine JSON array inside array Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I am trying to merge values from json array that has 2 or more arrays to one json array.

I see many similar questions but I could not find a solution. I tried a long way that did not succeed and there are certainly shorter and more beautiful ways.

I have json object like:

```
 [
    [
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R02-03"
                },
                "subject": "001-BB"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R02-03"
                },
                "subject": "002-CC"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R01-02"
                },
                "subject": "010-A1"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R33-33"
                },
                "subject": "011-AB"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
                },
                "subject": "001-BB"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
                },
                "subject": "002-CC"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032333"
                },
                "subject": "99-001"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032111"
                },
                "subject": "test-111"
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

I want the result will be accoding to the subject key, if the subject key value does not exist in the other array the value should be zero.

Expected Result:

```
[
    [
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value0": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R02-03"
                },
                "value1": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
                },
                "subject": "001-BB"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value0": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R02-03"
                },
                "value1": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
                },
                "subject": "002-CC"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value0": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R01-02"
                },
                "value1": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": null
                },
                "subject": "010-A1"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value0": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R33-33"
                },
                "value1": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": null
                },
                "subject": "011-AB"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value0": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": null
                },
                "value1": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032333"
                },
                "subject": "99-001"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                 "value0": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": null
                },
                "value1": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032111"
                },
                "subject": "test-111"
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

NOTE: The main array can be inclode more than 2 arrays.

Comment: So what did you try? It is not hard to do this.. Recursion all the way ;)

Comment: you can do something like this
`const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [3,4,5];
const arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2];`

Comment: @GuyT - Thank you, Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Majid Thank you for the response. I need to combine them no to concat them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine a is your given JSON Array.

```
let finalArray = []
/* putting all single json in finalArray */
let b = a.map(value => {
    value.map(val => {
        finalArray.push(val)
    })
})

let v = []

finalArray.map((val, idx) => {
    /* filtering all duplicate subjects and putting in to another array v */ 
    v[idx] = finalArray.filter(value => {
        return val.f_measure_function.subject == value.f_measure_function.subject
    })
})

let c = v.map(value => {
     /* creating the final array as you want */
    let va = {"f_measure_function": {}}

    value.forEach((val, idx) => {
        va.f_measure_function["value" + idx] = val.f_measure_function.value
    })

    va.f_measure_function["subject"] = value[0].f_measure_function.subject

    return va
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(c))
```

Comment: That you for the response!, It seems very nice. But it returns json like:`{
    "f_measure_function": {
        "value0": {
            "item_type": "ST",
            "Randomization number": "R02-03"
        },
        "value1": {
            "item_type": "INT",
            "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
        },
        "subject": "001-BB"
    }
}`

Comment: i think its generates output as you described. please tell me where m going wrong !

Comment: My mistake, I'm sorry. I returned the json object from a wrong place. Thanks a lot for you!

Comment: In the result I have duplicate rows, 2 rows for each subject :(

Comment: In the end of your code I added: `var uniq = new Set(c.map(e => JSON.stringify(e)));

var res = Array.from(uniq).map(e => JSON.parse(e));` and it fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an object to help parsing. There are probably way better solutions but this one does the trick!

```js
var JSONstring = document.querySelector('#JSONstring').textContent;

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSONstring);

var results = [];

var resultsObj = {};

var maxValLen = 0;

for (var i=0; i<parsedJSON.length; i++) {
  var array = parsedJSON[i];
  for (var j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
    var item = array[j].f_measure_function;
    if (!resultsObj[item.subject]) {
      resultsObj[item.subject] = [];
    }
    resultsObj[item.subject].push(item.value);
    if (resultsObj[item.subject].length > maxValLen) {
      maxValLen = resultsObj[item.subject].length;
    }
  }
}

for (var subject in resultsObj) {
  var valuesArray = resultsObj[subject];
  var measure = {
    subject: subject
  };
  for (var v=0; v<maxValLen; v++) {
    measure['value'+v] = valuesArray[v] || "null";
  }
  results.push({
    f_measure_function: measure
  })
}

console.log(results);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<code id="JSONstring" class="hidden">
[
    [
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R02-03"
                },
                "subject": "001-BB"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R02-03"
                },
                "subject": "002-CC"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R01-02"
                },
                "subject": "010-A1"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R33-33"
                },
                "subject": "011-AB"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
                },
                "subject": "001-BB"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
                },
                "subject": "002-CC"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032333"
                },
                "subject": "99-001"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032111"
                },
                "subject": "test-111"
            }
        }
    ]
]
</code>
```

Comment: Thank you! But in your result there is just value0 for each subject, there should be 2 values for each subject, value0 and value1 (in this case), for each array should be valueX, value0, value1 and so on. Please see my Expected Result

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo ... it' fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine!  I prefer another solution that more short.

Comment: if there is no value for the specific subject it shoule be null\zero, for example: value1 for "010-A1" subject should be appear with null value

Comment: Updated, all working as expected! I thought you were going with another solution. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

I divided the work so that it will be more easy to get to the solution with only two arrays in the main array.

About the **NOTE** indicating that the main array may contain more than two arrays **I think you should indicate how the merge will be done since it looks ambiguous**.

Hope this will help.

```js
let arr = [
    [
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R02-03"
                },
                "subject": "001-BB"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R02-03"
                },
                "subject": "002-CC"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R01-02"
                },
                "subject": "010-A1"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "ST",
                    "Randomization number": "R33-33"
                },
                "subject": "011-AB"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
                },
                "subject": "001-BB"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032355"
                },
                "subject": "002-CC"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032333"
                },
                "subject": "99-001"
            }
        },
        {
            "f_measure_function": {
                "value": {
                    "item_type": "INT",
                    "Serial number of device given to the subject": "13032111"
                },
                "subject": "test-111"
            }
        }
    ]
]

//first array containing the subjects of the first array
let subArr1 = arr[0].map((e) => e.f_measure_function.subject);
//second array containing the subjects of the second array
let subArr2 = arr[1].map((e) => e.f_measure_function.subject);

//our final array that will contain the result
let finalArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < subArr1.length; i++) {
    
    //the sample object for every new item and we will only modify three values of it
    const newObject = {
        "f_measure_function": {
            "value0": {
                "item_type": "ST",
                "Randomization number": ""
            },
            "value1": {
                "item_type": "INT",
                "Serial number of device given to the subject": ""
            },
            "subject": ""
        }
    };
    let subj = subArr1[i];
    newObject.f_measure_function.value0["Randomization number"] =
    arr[0][i].f_measure_function.value["Randomization number"];
     
    newObject.f_measure_function.subject = subj;  
    
    //test if the subject exists in the second array
    if (subArr2.includes(subj)) {
        newObject.f_measure_function.value1 = arr[1][i]["f_measure_function"]["value"];
    }
    else {
        newObject.f_measure_function.value1["Serial number of device given to the subject"]= null;
    }

    finalArray.push(newObject);
}

for (let i = 0; i < subArr2.length; i++) {
    const newObject = {
        "f_measure_function": {
            "value0": {
                "item_type": "ST",
                "Randomization number": ""
            },
            "value1": {
                "item_type": "INT",
                "Serial number of device given to the subject": ""
            },
            "subject": ""
        }
    };
    let subj =subArr2[i];
    newObject.f_measure_function.value1 = arr[1][i].f_measure_function.value;
    newObject.f_measure_function.subject = subj;
    
    
    //test if the subject exists in the first array
    if (subArr1.includes(subj)) {
        newObject.f_measure_function.value0["Randomization number"] = arr[0][i].f_measure_function.value["Randomization number"];
    }
    else {
        newObject.f_measure_function.value0["Randomization number"] = null;
    }
    //console.log(newObject)
    finalArray.push(newObject); 
}
//console.log(finalArray);

const pre = document.getElementById("result");
pre.innerHTML =JSON.stringify(finalArray,undefined,2);
```

```html
<pre id="result" class="prettyprint">
    
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, , I prefer another solution that more short.

Comment: but I thought that the other answers do not give the correct output since there are results without either value0 or value1 .